# Restrict object movement inside irregular shaped container

Tags: unity

I want to restrict object movement inside an area. My object follows cursor position.

I have already done that for the area border using Mathf.Champ to the translate because the borders are square shaped (got the idea from [Unity: Restrict movement inside a gameobject (2D)](https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/101893/unity-restrict-movement-inside-a-gameobject-2d)). The thing is that inside the box area there can also be other shapes (colliders) which I don't want my object to go over.

I know people suggest using physic collisions, but my game needs a unit perfect positions so I can't use physics due to physics' default contact offset (the one physics use to detect collisions).

Here is a short video of what I have:

https://gfycat.com/cookedsmartannelid

As you can see, movement is restricted (clamped) inside the box area but I want the movement to also be restricted to not go over the black area.

Is there a way to be able to do this with just clamping or do I need a raycast system or something like that?

Comment: The contact offset doesn't seem like it should be a deal-breaker here. You can scale down your colliders or offset your queries to compensate, and round the outcomes to "unit perfect positions" wherever you need.